# Flutter Doctor Searching wrong JAVA_HOME

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, java-home, flutter-doctor

I have set JAVA_HOME to: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`

When I run `flutter doctor` on my terminal, I get no errors. When I run `flutter doctor` on Visual Studio Code, I get an error:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jcastro2/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/bin/java
    ✗ Cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/bin/java to determine the version
```

The directory that it is searching in does not exist. How can I point it to the correct JAVA_HOME directory?

Answer (score 1):

There are problem in `Mac M1` processors and flutter solve until now.

Comment: so I can't build my flutter app for android?

Comment: you need windows or Mac with Intel processors, the same problem with windows if AMD Ryzen proccessors.

Comment: I have a Macbook Pro 2019, which has an Intel processor